# Ajax requests in the RESTful client

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, rest, curl

I work with a `Java RESTful` service and the consuming client. The Java app is receiving and delivering the data in the `JSON` format. I need to talk about 2 requests and their implementations in the consuming `RESTful client`.

If I click a button, a `WalletInfo` entity is generated and stored in the database. It has properties like `id`, `name`, `address` and the `currency`. The click is essentially a `POST` request.

The definition is provided,

```
@POST
@Path("generateAddress")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
WalletInfo generateAddress(GenerateWallet generateWallet);
```

This is the implementation,

```
public synchronized WalletInfo generateAddress(GenerateWallet generateWallet) {

        String walletName = generateWallet.getWalletName();

        String currencyName = generateWallet.getCurrencyName();

        WalletInfo walletInfo = iWalletInfoDao.getWalletInfoWithWalletNameAndCurrency(walletName, currencyName);

        return walletInfo; 
      }
```

I use this `cURL` command to do the `POST` request,

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"walletName": "Rome12345","currencyName":"Bitcoin"}' http://localhost:8080/rest/wallet/generateAddress
```

As it's the `POST` request, obviously, it doesn't return anything in the `terminal`. I have another `GET` request, the definition is provided,

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("currencyandname/{walletName}/{currencyName}")
WalletInfo getWalletInfoWithCurrencyAndWalletName(@PathParam("walletName") String walletName,
                                                  @PathParam("currencyName") String currencyName);
```

Here is the implementation,

```
public WalletInfo getWalletInfoWithCurrencyAndWalletName(String walletName, String currencyName) {
        return iWalletInfoDao.getWalletInfoWithWalletNameAndCurrency(walletName, currencyName);
    }
```

I do the `cURL` request like this for the execution,

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/rest/wallet/currencyandname/test1/Bitcoin | json
```

If the name and the currency info matches with the info in the database, it returns the info for the `WalletInfo` entity. For example, we provide the name `test1` and the currency `Bitcoin` using the cURL request and get something like in the terminal,

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "test1",
  "address": "mp51mPC38Wtcmybdyd9MPEB2bKnw6eYbCs",
  "currency": "Bitcoin"
}
```

If there is no match, we get nothing. And when we get a match, we can use other info, primarily, the address.

Let's talk about the client. As I said earlier, there is a button in the consuming client to generate the address and to fill a drop-down with that address. After the click of the button, the following `POST` request will be executed in the client,

```
   var dataValue = {
        "walletName":  "walletName",
        "currencyName": "selectedCurrency"
    };

  dataValue = JSON.stringify(dataValue);

  $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "www.hostdomain.com" + "/rest/wallet/generateAddress",
        data: dataValue,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){ 

           // the GET request code will be here                   
        },
        failure: function(errMsg) {

            // alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
```

Is the POST request is correct? I mean when I do the `POST` CURL command in the terminal, I get nothing in return. But, the `success function(data)` seems to need `data` as the input parameter after the successful execution of the `POST` request. I also have the `WalletEntity` as the return type in the Java method.

`2nd Question`

If the `POST` request is successful that means a WalletEntity is generated and stored in the MySQL. Now, I would like to do a `GET` request to get the same `WalletInfo` entity using the name/ currency name and use the address parameter from that instance.

It needs to be inside the `success: function(data)` of the `POST` request as we will only do the GET request after successful creation of the wallet and will use the `getWalletInfoWithCurrencyAndWalletName` method of the Java app for this purpose. I image the `GET` request like something,

```
$.ajax({
            url: "www.hostdomain.com"+ "/rest/wallet/currencyandname/" + "wallet_Name" + "/" + "selected_Currency",

            type: "GET",

            dataType: "json",

            success: function (data) {

                // I should have the WalletEntity here as the data
                // from the `GET` request 

                $("#address").append($('<option></option>').attr("value", "1").text(walletName + " " + data['address'].toString()));
            }
        });
```

I assume the data is the `WalletEntity` and address is one of it's parameters. So, If I would like to only have the `address`, I need to write like `data['address']` for the purpose.

Is this the `GET` request in the client is correct? We only do if the POST request is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accroding to your code, it should return data after do the post request if no error was happen. So i advice you to do these things to check if the post request was processed successfully:

1. press `f12` in your browser, check the **NetWork** tab, and see the
   request process response, if the response is empty, them do the next
   step;
2. set a **breakpoint** in the `generateAddress` method, and then debug step
   by step, see what will happened.

Comment: After seeing the `syntax`, do you find the code is correct? I haven't deployed the `Java app` and hence, the `Ajax` requests in the client doesn't
work

Comment: @Artin then you can set a breakpoint in the `generateAddress` method, and then send a request by `curl` on command line, as the step 2 I said.

Comment: Good idea, I will try to see